# Production iOS Push Notification sent locally but not from aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am able to send a notification from my own machine with production certificate and it is reaching to my iPhone correctly, but when I deploy to my aws elastic beanstalk server it still says that the connection to APNS server was successful but the notification is not reaching anymore to my device.

I am using Grails 2.3, Java 1.7, and the Grails Plugin for APNS "Apple Push Notification Service Integration" that wraps the Java plugin java-apns for Grails.

I don´t know why the notification is not reaching to my device with elastic beanstalk if it is working well locally, besides it says that the connection to the APNS server is ok in both cases

Comment: It's just "Grails", it's never been called "Groovy on Grails". See http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to tweak inbound connections settings for your elastic beanstalk setup.

Have a look on "IP Address Range Used by the Push Service"
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html